# Change ffmpeg input while streaming

Tags: bash

Is there a way to change ffmpeg input while streaming to rtmp?
I have this bash script

```sh
 #! /bin/bash

VBR="1500k"
FPS="24"
QUAL="superfast"

RTMP_URL="rtmp://live.live/live"
KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
VIDEO_SOURCE="video.mp4"
AUDIO_SOURCE="song.mp3"
NP_SOURCE="song.txt"
FONT="font.ttf"

ffmpeg \
    -re -f lavfi -i "movie=filename=$VIDEO_SOURCE:loop=0, setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)" \
    -thread_queue_size 512 -i "$AUDIO_SOURCE" \
    -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 \
    -map_metadata:g 1:g \
    -vf drawtext="fontsize=25: fontfile=$FONT: \
        box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=20: \
        textfile=$NP_SOURCE: reload=1: fontcolor=white@0.8: x=50: y=50" \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale:v 3 -b:a 320000 -bufsize 512k \
    -f flv "$RTMP_URL/$KEY"
```

What i want to do is to be able to change  VIDEO_SOURCE on the fly, i was thinking if it's possible to make the input a directory then change the video in that directory on the fly, i'm new to dealing with scripts so i don't know how to do that

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737129/change-ffmpeg-input-on-the-fly) will help.

Comment: The video will be played in a loop, i want to change the looping in video on the fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete guess, based on what little I know about how `ffmpeg` handles interactive input:

```
while :; do

    ffmpeg \
        -re -f lavfi -i "movie=filename=$VIDEO_SOURCE:loop=0, setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)" \
        -thread_queue_size 512 -i "$AUDIO_SOURCE" \
        -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 \
        -map_metadata:g 1:g \
        -vf drawtext="fontsize=25: fontfile=$FONT: \
            box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=20: \
            textfile=$NP_SOURCE: reload=1: fontcolor=white@0.8: x=50: y=50" \
        -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
        -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale:v 3 -b:a 320000 -bufsize 512k \
        -f flv "$RTMP_URL/$KEY"

    read -p "Next movie?" VIDEO_SOURCE
    [ "$VIDEO_SOURCE" = q ] && break
done
```

`ffmpeg` should(?) exit if you send `q` to standard input. Your script will then prompt you for a new value for `VIDEO_SOURCE`. If you type `q` again, the loop exits. Otherwise, it restarts `ffmpeg` with the new video source file.

If this works, you can perhaps adapt it for something closer to your needs.